# Is The Following VB.NET Implementation Of Random Thread-Safe?

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, random

I know there are many thread-safety questions especially regarding the Random class in VB.NET and C#. I've read through several as well as a blog post from Jon Skeet (https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/); yet I'm still having a difficult time assessing the thread safety of my piece of code. I apologize a priori for adding yet another question of this form.

My code is based off of the aforementioned blog post, but I *attempted* to implement the comments from Andrew Shapira near the bottom of the post.

**Background**: Any code that calls this class (directly or indirectly) is typically ran on multiple threads without the use of any type of thread-locking. While I understand I can pass the onus of thread safety to any calling code, I would prefer to make this class handle multiple threads on its own.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Imports System.Threading

Public NotInheritable Class ThreadSafeRandom

    Private Shared globalSeed As Integer = 0

    Private Shared Function CreateRandom(ByVal initialSeed As Integer) As Random

        Dim newRandom As Random

        If initialSeed <> 0 Then
            newRandom = New Random(initialSeed)
            Return newRandom
        End If

        Dim seed As Integer = CInt(Now.Ticks And &HFFFF)

        Interlocked.CompareExchange(globalSeed, seed, 0)

        newRandom = New Random(globalSeed)

        Interlocked.Increment(globalSeed)

        Return newRandom
    End Function

    Public Shared Function RandomInteger(ByVal lowerBound As Integer,
                                         ByVal exclusiveUpperBound As Integer,
                                         Optional ByVal seed As Integer = 0) As Integer

        Dim newRandom As Random = CreateRandom(seed)
        Return newRandom.Next(lowerBound, exclusiveUpperBound)
    End Function
End Class
```

**Explanation**: `globalSeed` is the value that gets passed into the `Random` constructor by default. Every time it gets passed, it gets incremented via `System.Threading.Interlocked` in the `CreateRandom` function.

`CreateRandom` is the `Private` function that is called within the `Public` function `RandomInteger`. The dual purpose of `CreateRandom` is to assure that the same seed value is never passed while at the same time allows for a new `Random` object to always be created thus avoiding potential thread issues.

Lastly, in order to allow a user to replicate results, the class allows for user-inputted seed values.

**Question(s)**: Is ThreadSafeRandom truly thread safe? If not, is it possible to implement it in thread-safe way without completely changing the implementation?

Comment: I no longer recommend this general approach - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376888 and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx. I would just stick with a single instance of `Random` and a lock, these days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask if your implementation is thread-safe. I'd say that, in *some* sense of the term, yes it is. But careful here. [What is this thing you call "thread safe"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe/). I'd agree the code is thread-safe in the sense that the program will run safely without corrupting data structures. But will the code do what you want and need (including meet goals you may not realize you have) under concurrent scenarios? That's debatable.

I think the first thing I would worry about with the code you posted is whether it's actually *useful*. Three major issues stand out to me:

1. A caller wanting to use a single seed value and get a sequence of random numbers in a given range is out of luck. They will get a whole new `Random` instance with each call to `RandomInteger()`, and that instance will always return the same number.
2. You're only using 16 bits of the `Tick` value. This seems like a needless reduction of entropy. Why not use `&H7FFFFFFF`?
3. There is not actually anything stopping two different threads from getting the same seed (which *seemed* to be a goal of yours).
4. Creating an instance of `Random` is not inexpensive. So this approach to thread-safety is very costly. I'm sure compared to just using `lock`, the latter would win hands-down.

On top of all of that, there is of course the problem of creating a sequence of `Random` objects by seeding them with an incrementing value. See the various articles cited in [Jon's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638604/is-the-following-vb-net-implementation-of-random-thread-safe#comment72404892_42638604) and also below.

Based on the valuable discussion found in those references, I would say that there are two obvious, simple, and useful ways to approach the problem, depending on what you need.

If each thread operates completely independently from each other, and thus any correlation between multiple instance of `Random` will be irrelevant, then the `ThreadLocal<T>` or `[ThreadStatic]` approaches should be fine. E.g.:

```
private static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> _threadRandom =
    new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random());
public static Random Instance { get { return _threadRandom.Value; } }
```

or…

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static Random _threadRandom;

public static Random Instance
{
    get
    {
        if (_threadRandom == null)
        {
            _threadRandom = new Random();
        }

        return _threadRandom;
    }
}
```

If you need for multiple threads to operate together in a way that correlated sequences of random numbers would be a problem, then you should just use a single `Random` instance with a `lock`:

```
static class SharedRandom
{
    private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

    public static int Next()
    {
        lock (_random)
        {
            return _random.Next();
        }
    }

    // etc...wrap each `Random` method you need, as above
}
```

Useful references (you know about all of these…I'm just putting them here all in one place for convenience, and because a couple were in the comments, which are ephemeral):
[Seeding Multiple Random Number Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36376888)
[C# in Depth: Random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx)
[How do I seed a random class to avoid getting duplicate random values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1785744)
[Jon Skeet's coding blog: Revisiting randomness](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/04/revisiting-randomness/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. I'm embarrassed by the first two issues you found, so I'm sorry for those careless mistakes. I'm a little confused by your third point though. Can you explain how two threads can get the same seed? The purpose of `globalSeed` was to increment each time `RandomInteger` is called (via `CreateRandom`), and this is done via `Interlocked`.

Comment: @basketballfan22: the call to `Interlocked.Increment()` ensures that the field is incremented safely. But it does nothing to ensure that two threads don't both use the same value for the field. If thread A calls `CreateRandom()` and gets as far as the assignment to `newRandom` but then is suspended (preempted) before it calls `Increment()`, then thread B can call `CreateRandom()` and use the same value for `globalSeed` that thread A did, because thread A didn't get a chance to update the value before thread B came along.

Comment: Jeepers, I'm even more embarrassed that I couldn't see that. On a different note, do you believe I should delete this question? Seeing how it was already practically redundant and how my attempt was rather pathetic, I'm not sure if it serves any purpose. I do appreciate your answer as well as the links you provided though, and it is nice to have all those references in one location as opposed to having to "scour" the Internet like I had to. I'll defer to a more experienced and knowledgeable member on that decision though.

Comment: _"do you believe I should delete this question?"_ -- I don't have a strong feeling one way or the other. I understand your reluctance to keep it, and it's your question to delete if you want. I won't be offended if you do. On the other hand, there can be value in a critique of code, whether that code is correct or not. Sometimes a critique of incorrect code is even more useful. If you feel your question _directly_ duplicates some existing question, consider instead voting to close as a duplicate, so your question can become a "sign post" question (i.e. help lead others to the original).